# Should I capitalize the first letter of the first word in the body of a letter?

Tags: capitalization

> Sehr geehrter Herr Robert
>
> (s)eit zwei Wochen.....
>
> Mit freundlichen Gruessen

Should I capitalize the (s) or not? In many video I saw it wasn't capitalize, so it that the general rule?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends on the punctuation you use at the end of the greeting line, "Sehr geehrter Herr Robert".

As it stands, you don't have any, which is wrong anyway. You can either end it with an exclamation mark (old style), in which case you have to start the first word of the text "Seit" with a capital "S". Or you end it with a comma (current style), in which case the first word of the text is not capitalized.

So either you write:

> Sehr geehrter Herr Robert!
>
> Seit zwei Wochen ...

Or:

> Sehr geehrter Herr Robert,
>
> seit zwei Wochen ...

Comment: To give some time perspective, the exclamation mark was being phased out back when I went to school in the 1980s.

Comment: Oh, and *please* no `!` at the end of the greeting. That's an *exclamation* mark, "exclamation" as in "shouting". You don't want to shout your greeting.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica I think you are incorrectly applying your English language feel to German here. The exclamation mark was the standard punctuation at the end of the greeting until about 50 years ago, and nobody felt like shouting when using it, or like being shouted at when being so addressed.

Comment: "As it stands, you don't have any, which is wrong anyway." – Keep in mind that this depends on the country. In Switzerland, no punctuation is used after the salutation and the beginning of the next line is capitalized. Given the closing line in the OP ("Grüssen" instead of "Grüßen"), they may be located in Switzerland.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt Nope. I actually know German better than English. The exclamation mark has been phased out since so long ago that it's downright irritating to see it, instantly giving the letter a quaint feeling...

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica This may be because you are a bit younger than I am.

Comment: @Mophotla I suggest you write an answer to that effect. I am not that familiar with Swiss German so I'll stand back on that.

Comment: @Mophotla: The closing line doesn't contain "Grüssen" it contains "Gruessen" - which suggests to me that the OP doesn't have easy access to non-ASCII characters, rather than they are avoiding ß because they are in CH.

Comment: A former coworker even used to write "Grueßen". Asked about the sense, he told me that he wanted to avoid non-ASCII characters. Well...

Comment: Note that the greeting line reads strange because it mixes formal ("Sehr geehrter", "Herr") elements with the use of only a firstname which is informal. The combination of "Herr Robert" itself is super uncommon in both written and spoken German.

Comment: Robert can also be a last name in which case It wouldn't be uncommon at all.

Answer (score 11):

It depends - on the punctuation.

If the address of the person is - as usual and recommended - separated by a comma, then the sentence just continues and 'seit' is not the first word of a new sentence:

> Sehr geehrter Herr Robert,
>
> seit zwei Wochen..

One can use an exclamation mark at the end of the address to the person. That's [meanwhile uncommon and considered deprecated](https://www.textskizzen.de/satzzeichen-briefanrede/). In that case 'Seit' starts a new sentence and hence is capitalized:

> Sehr geehrter Herr Robert!
>
> Seit zwei Wochen...

Comment: Do you maybe have a less spammy link?

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Still just one person’s opinion there, but that page looks much nicer. Thanks.

Comment: Pages like Duden don't elaborate well on the usage - thus are not much help. These communication coaching guides (as much as they want to sell their service) are much better in these cases.

Comment: @CarstenS, `Still just one person’s opinion there` - considering that almost everything written on StackExchange is more or less the opinion of the respective author, and very few SE's formally require citations or justifications of any kind, that seems not particularly important... the voting mechanism will take care of that.

Comment: @AnoE, I did not think that the answer requires an authoritative reference, I just wanted to point out that the link is none so that I am not sure how much value it adds. In other words, planetmaker’s one person opinion would have been good enough for me :) I wasn’t very clear on that, so thank you.
I also don’t mind the link, and I probably wouldn’t have said anything to begin with if I hadn’t found the original link rather ugly.

Comment: Cheers, @CarstenS, I understood now. :)

Answer (score 2):

In German, that letter is *not* capitalized.

The first word of the first sentence of the letter is "Sehr", which is capitalized, while "seit" is in the middle of that sentence.

Comment: Interesting, then why don't they put Sehr in the same line if it is the first word

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai: I don't think orthography precludes inserting linebreaks after any words in a sentence. In fact, poems routinely do that, break lines without making use of the available horizontal space.

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai Because the "Sehr" is part of the greeting, even though it's also the start of the first sentence. That's why you must add a comma at the end of the greeting, because the sentence continues after that. And because the sentence continues after the greeting, you do not capitalize the first word after the comma. The newline separates the greeting from the body, but the first sentence extends over the boundary.